# CQWP - displaying Author, Check Out To, etc... from multiple libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, content-query-web-part

I have a CQWP that I created which lists the document icon, title, Author, Checked Out To, and Last Modified. Everything displays fine if I point it at a single document library but when I point it to the subsite, in order to see documents from all libraries, I get the icon and title but nothing else. What am I missing? Here is my code from the ItemStyle.xsl:

```
   <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
    <div style="float:left; width:32px;">&#160;</div>     
    <div style="float:left; width:15%; padding-right:15px;">Name</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:10%; padding-right:15px;">Created By</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:10%; padding-right:15px;">Checked Out</div>
    <div style="float:left;">Last Modified</div>
</xsl:if>

   <div class="item link-item">
       <xsl:if test="string-length(@DocumentIconImageUrl) != 0">
           <div class="image-area-left" style="width:25px;">
               <img class="image" src="{@DocumentIconImageUrl}" title="" />
           </div>
       </xsl:if>
       <div class="link-item">
       <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">

       </xsl:if>
           <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
           <div style="float:left; width:15%; padding-right:15px;">
            <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
                <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
                  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
                  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
            </a>
        </div>
           <div style="float:left; width:10%; padding-right:15px;">
             <xsl:value-of select="@Author" />
            </div>
           <div style="float:left; width:10%; padding-right:15px;">
             <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="string-length(@CheckoutUser) = 0">
               Checked In
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="@CheckoutUser" /> 
              </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>              
           </div>
           <div style="float:left;"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Modified, 1033, 2)" /></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

here is the code from my CQWP:

```
<metaData>
  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
<data>
  <properties>
    <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">And</property>
    <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
    <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
    <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
    <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
    <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
    <property name="ListName" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterDisplayValue3" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterDisplayValue2" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterDisplayValue1" type="string">In Progress</property>
    <property name="FilterField1" type="string">{6e2d20e1-63ca-44c4-a57f-1f934d7f92ab}</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">Displays a dynamic view of content from your site.</property>
    <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string" />
    <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
    <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
    <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
    <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
    <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" />
    <property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},Lookup;{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},Text;{1df5e554-ec7e-46a6-901d-d85a3881cb18},User;</property>
    <property name="Title" type="string">In Progress</property>
    <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
    <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="Filter1IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
    <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string">DateTime</property>
    <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
    <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">WithDocIcon</property>
    <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;dsQueryResponse&gt;
                &lt;Rows&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" /&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                &lt;/Rows&gt;
                &lt;/dsQueryResponse&gt;</property>
    <property name="FilterIncludeChildren2" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
    <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">101</property>
    <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Modified,DateTime,;Modified By,User;Checked Out To, User;Check In Comment, Lookup;Author,User</property>
    <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
    <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
    <property name="ListGuid" type="string" />
    <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
    <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string" />
    <property name="Default" type="string" />
    <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
    <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
    <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
    <property name="FilterByContextTerm" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="PlayMediaInBrowser" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
    <property name="Xsl" type="string">&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" &gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /&gt; &lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</property>
    <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
    <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
    <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
    <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" />
    <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Height" type="string" />
    <property name="DataMappings" type="string">Author:|Modified:|Description:{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},ShortComment,Text;{1df5e554-ec7e-46a6-901d-d85a3881cb18},Author,User;|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|CheckoutUser:|LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|</property>
    <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterIncludeChildren1" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
    <property name="MainXslLink" type="string" />
    <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="FilterValue1" type="string">In Progress</property>
    <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
    <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
    <property name="Filter3IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
    <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="FilterIncludeChildren3" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="EnableOriginalValue" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
    <property name="FilterType1" type="string">Choice</property>
    <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
    <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string" />
    <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="WebUrl" type="string">~sitecollection/dmwdocs</property>
    <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string" />
    <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
    <property name="Filter2IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
    <property name="MediaPlayerStyleSource" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
    <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
    <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
    <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
    <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
    <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
    <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
    <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="Width" type="string" />
  </properties>
</data>
```

Comment: Are you able to also export the CQWP, open it in your favorite text editor, and add that code to the question as well? In a case like this it might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing web part property as shown in screen shot.[CQWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmq2X.jpg) 
Here I have mentioned the column names explicitly in 'Fields to display' section. Please use display names. 
In my case it was not showing Author(Created by) column .

Comment: That's it! I have spent all this time looking at the code and it didn't dawn on my I actually and to put the values in the 'Fields to display' section. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For those of us that can't see the screenshot. Which is the "Fields to display" section? Is it CommonViewFields or ViewFieldsOverride ? Did you use the CDATA syntax?